# Django HttpResponseRedirect Results in 404 Error on IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, httpresponse

I have a Django project called investigations which includes an app called alerts. The project worked in development but, while deploying to IIS, I had to change the URLs, and now an HttpResponseRedirect call is not working in one of my views. I tried the project with the new URLs in development...and it worked perfectly.

Here is the view:

```
def alerts(request):
    newAlerts = Alert.objects.filter(disposition='')
    formset = AlertFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=newAlerts)
    helper = AlertFormsetHelper()
    context = {'formset':formset, 'helper':helper}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for form in formset:
            if form.is_valid():
                if form.has_changed():
                    if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        entity = form.cleaned_data['entity']
                        messages.success(request, 'SUCCESS: Alert for %s was dispositioned' % entity)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/alerts')
    return render(request, 'alerts/alerts.html', context)
```

The page renders correctly when going to domainname/investigations/alerts. However, when a submit button is hit to save the changed form in the formset, a 404 error with no accompanying detail is returned. The address in the address bar is still domainname/investigations/alerts, as it should be.

Here are the `urlpatterns` in `urls.py` for the alerts app:

```
url(r'^investigations/$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'investigations/alerts', views.alerts, name='alerts')
```

Why is the HttpResponseRedirect redirecting to the same page (as it should be) but returning a 404 error instead of the page itself?

**Edit:**

Per request, here is the full urls.py for the app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^investigations/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^investigations/alerts/$', views.alerts, name='alerts'),
    url(r'^investigations/search/$', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

And the main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from alerts import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('alerts.urls')),
]
```

And the view now looks like this:

```
def alerts(request):
    newAlerts = Alert.objects.filter(disposition='')
    formset = AlertFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=newAlerts)
    helper = AlertFormsetHelper()
    context = {'formset':formset, 'helper':helper}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for form in formset:
            if form.is_valid():
                if form.has_changed():
                    if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        entity = form.cleaned_data['entity']
                        messages.success(request, 'SUCCESS: Alert for %s was dispositioned' % entity)
        return redirect('alerts')
    return render(request, 'alerts/alerts.html', context)
```

Comment: You should format your url patterns constitently. Sloppy url patterns is often the cause of these kinds of problems. `url(r'^investigations/alerts/$', views.alerts, name='alerts')`

Comment: thanks for the tip - unfortunately, the issue still persists

Comment: Yes. The problem must be something else. Since you are calling `return HttpResponseRedirect('/alerts')`, it's very puzzling that you are redirected to `domainname/investigations/alerts`. Are you sure this is the actual view code that is used? Can you post the main urls.py and the full urls.py for the alerts app?

Comment: Also, run this with DEBUG=True and post the 404 error page message. It should show all the url patterns that was tried.

Comment: Check my edit. This is running with DEBUG=True, which is why it is confusing that there is no detail

Comment: Show the changes you did to the view, if any.

Comment: If DEBUG=True, then a 404 page without "Tried these patterns" usually indicates that some view (or maybe middleware) has raised the `Http404` exeception.

Comment: what should I look for to check for that? this view works fine in development with the only thing changing being that `investigations` was added to the urls

Comment: You could try entering some arbitrary invalid url and see if you get the expected debug 404 page. It should only show the admin url patterns and the three investigations urls.

Comment: i changed it to `redirect(reverse('giraffe'))`. No luck - same 404 page with no detail

Comment: Ok. Well then it's clear that the line is never executed. This should have caused a ReverseNotFound exception. But what I meant was that you should manually enter an invalid url into the browser to get the debug page. With `redirect()`, you don't need `reverse()` as well. `redirect('alerts')` will do url reversing and return a HttpRedirectResponse.

Comment: okay - i removed the reverse, thank you. what do you think i should try next? i didn't change any other lines from the version that works in development.

Comment: I suspect that there's code somewhere that raises an `Http404` exception. Django will catch it and return a 404 page. It could be in some middleware or even in one of the formset classes? `Form.is_valid()` will trigger the `clean()` methods of the relevant forms and model classes. Either use a debugger to step through the code, or do a grep search for `404` in your code. Are you using `get-object-or-404()` somewhere?

Comment: no, not using that anywhere. don't know how to grep on Windows, but I'm pretty sure there's no `404` anywhere.

Comment: Did you change the url as @HåkenLid said in the first comment? `url(r'^investigations/alerts/$', views.alerts, name='alerts')` . If not it will raise the 404 error.

Comment: yes, i did - the current state of everything is under the edit section in my post

Comment: You'll just have to debug it. Either use a line debugger such as pdb or werkzeug, or add a bunch of logging/print calls. My guess is that this view never returns, but raises a 404 exception instead.

Comment: pdb and its ilk would only work with a development server, right? where you could see the requests? same thing with print statements, i believe. this is in production on IIS.

Comment: an alternative is to install https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to your project.  This is a default inclusion on all my django projects, and the `show_urls` command will print out all the URLs that Django is using with your project.

Comment: i will give that a shot. it's really weird, because i just tried the app in development on the production server (as opposed to development locally), and it worked. so the same exact django project works in development, but not in production.

Answer (score 3):

You're telling it to return to `/alerts`, where the actual URL defined for it is `investigations/alerts`

A better way for you to do this would use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

and do it like so:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('alerts'))
```

This would let you use the `name` kwarg you've already defined, so if you decide to change the URL, it won't matter if the name stays the same.

Comment: I tried 'investigations/alerts', and I also just tried the reverse method. The error remains the same: `404 - File or Directory not Found

Comment: It's even easier to use the convenience function `django.shortcuts.redirect()`, which you can pass either a url, a view name or a model instance with a `get_absolute_url()` method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue. I even tried hard coding the url with no luck